# Antlr commandline options through Java Api

Tags: antlr4, java

I was trying to set some [commandLine arguments](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/ANTLR+Tool+Command+Line+Options) while using the [Antlr4 api](http://www.antlr.org/api/JavaTool/index.html). The documentation does not clearly state how to do this. I tried to pass the arguments unsuccessfully while creating the `Tool` instance like this:

```
Tool tool = new Tool(new String[]{"-o ./myoutdir/ ./test.g4"});
```

This does not work. What is the right way to do so? I do not see anything relevant in the [documentation](http://www.antlr.org/api/JavaTool/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Tool tool = new Tool(new String[]{"-o", "./myoutdir/", "./test.g4"});
```